# How does exportFunction work in Turbotable?

Tags: primeng, primeng-turbotable

How do we implement the exportFunction in the parameters of Turbotable.

According to the definition of PrimeNg exportFunction: A function to implement custom export. Need to return string value.

Is there anyone who has already used this feature in his chart and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this;

component;

```
exportFunction = (data,field) =>{
    console.log(data,field)
}
```

html;

```
<p-table ... [exportFunction]="exportFunction">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @foxgang , but what do you return in the function exportfunction ?, if you could show me an example.